# Sum quantity of a JSON Array with same key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a problem with javascript objects with arrays trying to update "quantity" if the selected item is choosen again.

The object I use is defined like this:

```
var Cart = {
    User: 0,
    Store: 0,
    UserID: 0, 
    Deliver: "Entrega",
    Date: "2014-01-01",
    Total: 0,
    ProductsCart: []
};
```

And in ProductsCart the array Im creating is the following:

```
Cart.ProductsCart.push({
        "ProductID": id,    //value sent from javascript function 
        "Quantity": Number(Quantity),
        "Price": Price.toFixed(2),
        "Name": name,
        "Desc": desc,
        "Date": date,
        "StoreID": store,
        "UserID": Number(UserID) //Special
```

The problem Im facing right now is that I have a javascript code to update the quantity of a selected product again, if exist it update the quantity but sometimes it works and sometimes not. This is the code

```
  var temp = {},
            i;

        for (i = Cart.ProductsCart.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
            ProductID = Cart.ProductsCart[i].ProductID;
            UserID = Cart.ProductsCart[i].NinoID;
            if (temp.hasOwnProperty(ProductID) && temp.hasOwnProperty(UserID)) {
                Cart.ProductsCart[temp[ProductID]].Quantity += Cart.ProductsCart[i].Quantity;
                //Splice to make one array with updated quantity?
                Cart.ProductsCart.splice(i, 1);
            } else {

                temp[ProductID] = i;
                //I need to identify one product per user and filter the productos by user so Im using that UserID to identify every array per user 
                temp[UserID] = UserID;
            }
        }
        console.log(Cart.ProductsCart);
```

Now the problem is that sometimes it add the specific quantity to the product like

- Pizza, Quantity 1
- Drink, Quantity 1

But for some reason for the same user or different user I try to add a **Cake, Quantity 1** the pizza or the Drink is altered in its quantity and the cake doesnt exist anymore. Hope you can guide where its the problem
Thanks in advance

**EDIT-------------**

The original script (mine) works with specific products, because doing some tests I found that Im using fullcalendar and on every click on a specific day the code doesnt work, but If i dont make a click the code works.

Other thing is that Im using AJAX to bring the products by categories, the problem is not getting the ID, the problem is they dont identify the existing array

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your array looks like this:

```
Pizza  4
Cake   3
Pizza  2
Pizza  5
Drink  2
```

At i = 2, you merge the two Pizza lines and splice one of them out:

```
Pizza  4
Cake   3
Pizza  7
Drink  2
```

The problem is, now you Pizza line is at index 2, not 3, but you still have `temp.Pizza = 3`. So, at i = 0, you will incorrectly merge into the Drink line, which is now at index 3.

One solution would be to go forward through the array when merging, instead of backward, and `splice()` the later repetitions of a product, leaving the first one at the index that you recorded. Then just make sure that you do `i -= 1` after splicing so that you'll look at that index again now that some other item has moved into that index.

Comment: Thans for the response, I have problems with english so I try to figure it out. The function is always called so the temp will be empty everytime it start to verify every product. Restar temp{}?

Comment: The problem is just that the indexes in `temp` will point to the wrong item because `splice` takes items out of the list.

Comment: Even without the splice(), the products are correct until certain point, because if I add other products, they are appending but other products are affected without splice()

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're splicing your array mid-loop, which will cause undesired effects. You are iterating over an array for every item in the array, yet you are changing the items in that array as you are iterating. Can you see how this would cause you problems? :)

Take this example, which you can see demoed on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Sxg7/).

```
var arr = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five"    
];

console.log('Without Splice ...');

for ( var i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++ ) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}

console.log('With Splice ...');

for ( var i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++ ) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    arr.splice(i, 1);
}
```

The first iteration logs each item, as you'd expect. The second iteration, though, logs only every other item (one, three, five). A safer bet would be to keep track of the items you want to remove in a temporary array, and then when you're iteration is done remove the items from your source based on what's in the temporary array.

Comment: Thans for the response, but how can I access to the Array after the iteration is done without the specific index?

Comment: @user3444084 I'm not sure what you mean. If you keep track of all the indices you "touched", you could then use that temp array to remove the items you wanted from Cart.ProductsCart.

Comment: Sorry but Im new to JSON and javascript, what I undestand is that my temp array (temp{}) is always empty after each iterations, so every time I add a new item it starts empty, but I dont know how to use that array and then remove it.

Comment: {} is not an array, but an object. var temp = []; would be an array. WHere you had the .splice(i, 1), you would just temp.push(i); and then, once your first iteration is over, you could splice out each index in the temp array.

Comment: At first I thought it was working as you comment, but the problem persist, maybe Im doing it wrong

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but I'm just not following your structure.

What I would do is make it so that you have an array of `Cart` objects and each `Cart` object would have essential items like the user the cart belongs to and what items and what quantity of those items:

```
/**
* @constructor
*/
var Cart = function(){
    var userID;
    var items = [];
    // array of Item
    ...
};

/**
* method for checking if item exists in cart
*/
Cart.prototype.hasItem = function(item){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
        if (this.items[i].itemId === item.itemId){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


/**
* method for checking if item exists in cart
*/
Cart.prototype.updateItemQty= function(item, difference){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
        if (this.items[i].itemId === item.itemId){
            this.items[i].qty += difference;
        }
    }
}
```

Define Item:

```
var Item = function() {
    var ItemId;
    var qty;
    ...
}
```

then keep an array of Cart

```
var carts = [];
```

now provide a method or function for adding items to a particular cart

```
function addItem(item, userId){
    for (var i = 0; i < carts.length; i++){
        if (carts[i].userId === userId){
            // add or update item
            if (carts[i].hasItem(item)){
                carts[i].updateItemQty(item, 1);
            } else {
                carts[i].addItem(item);
            }
        } else {
            // add a new cart to carts array first
            // then add the item to that new cart
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thans for your response but Im new to javascript and what Im doing if I change my actual array and methods will change everything on validations so it's a little dificult to implement something like this, or maybe Im wrong?

Comment: @user3444084 I'm not sure what you mean about validation.

Comment: Im using the Cart array to store more values by different users, in ProductsCart[] im using a "UserID", I need that to INSERT into a database and "validate" UserID for every product, so every time in a loop, will verify every product with specific UserID so every product has the specific user